# how to hide/show div with data filtering

Tags: html, hide, show

```
<script>
function changeContent(str)
{
    if(str == 'recent' || str == 'old' && !($(".main_content").is(':visible')))
    {
        $(".main_content").show();
    }
    else if( str == 'newComment') {
        $(".main_content").hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

The list options with onclick function to "changeContent()" with id as parameter..

```
<main class="cd-main-content">
        <div class="cd-tab-filter-wrapper">
            <div class="cd-tab-filter">
                <ul class="cd-filters">
                    <li class="placeholder"> 
                        <a data-type="all" href="#0">All</a> <!-- selected option on mobile -->
                    </li> 
                    <!-- <li class="filter"><a class="selected" href="#0" data-type="all">All</a></li> -->
                    <li class="filter" data-filter=".color-1"><a href="#0" id="recent" data-type="color-1" onclick="changeContent(this.id)">Recent to Old</a></li>
                    <li class="filter" data-filter=".color-2"><a href="#0" id="old" data-type="color-2" onclick="changeContent(this.id)">Old to Recent</a></li>
                    <li class="filter" ><a href="#0" id="newComment" data-type="color-3" onclick="changeContent(this.id)">New Comment</a></li>
                </ul> <!-- cd-filters -->
            </div> <!-- cd-tab-filter -->
        </div> <!-- cd-tab-filter-wrapper -->
```

the main div which should be hidden and shown ( along with data filter ),
the div is getting hidden/shown but the data filter is not working once its get hidden..

```
<div class="main_content">
        <section class="cd-gallery">
            <ul>
                <li class="mix color-1 check1 radio2 option3"><img src="img/img-1.jpg" alt="Image 1"></li>
                <li class="mix color-2 check2 radio2 option2"><img src="img/img-2.jpg" alt="Image 2"></li>
                <li class="mix color-1 check3 radio3 option1"><img src="img/img-3.jpg" alt="Image 3"></li>
                <li class="mix color-1 check3 radio2 option4"><img src="img/img-4.jpg" alt="Image 4"></li>
                <li class="mix color-1 check1 radio3 option2"><img src="img/img-5.jpg" alt="Image 5"></li>
                <li class="mix color-2 check2 radio3 option3"><img src="img/img-6.jpg" alt="Image 6"></li>
                <li class="mix color-2 check2 radio2 option1"><img src="img/img-7.jpg" alt="Image 7"></li>
                <li class="mix color-1 check1 radio3 option4"><img src="img/img-8.jpg" alt="Image 8"></li>
                <li class="mix color-2 check1 radio2 option3"><img src="img/img-9.jpg" alt="Image 9"></li>
                <li class="mix color-1 check3 radio2 option4"><img src="img/img-10.jpg" alt="Image 10"></li>
                <li class="mix color-1 check3 radio3 option2"><img src="img/img-11.jpg" alt="Image 11"></li>
                <li class="mix color-2 check1 radio3 option1"><img src="img/img-12.jpg" alt="Image 12"></li>
                <li class="gap"></li>
                <li class="gap"></li>
                <li class="gap"></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="cd-fail-message">No results found</div>
        </section> <!-- cd-gallery -->
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="new_content" style="display:none">
        </div> -->
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/70hg59ua/ The show/hide part seems to be working except the "All" link because it has no `onclick` function bound to it. What is your expected result?

Comment: @icke no.. there's isn't any error :)

Comment: @icke basically, when I click "New Comment" the div should be hidden and it's working perfect. And now when I click "Recent To Old " or "Old to Recent", the div is getting appeared, but the content is not getting filtered.

Comment: Well, you did not implement any filter. Are you asking how to implement the filtering/sorting of your list of CDs by date?

Comment: There's already functionality in the code to filter.. ( data-filter = ".color-1" ) But it's not working once the div gets hidden and then shown.

Comment: You added custom `data-*` attributes, but that doesn't mean that anything gets filtered automatically. You still need to implement that part.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/70hg59ua/2/ ?

Comment: Glad to help! I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an attribute like `data-filter` is not enough. You have to implement the filtering in some way.

For example you could do it in the `changeContent` function you already have.

You could:

```
var filter = "."+$("#"+str).attr("data-type");
```

get the class you want to filter by from the `data-type` attribute in your anchor tags and then

```
$(".main_content ul li"+filter).show();
```

show only those list items that match the class.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/70hg59ua/2/